# I Abandoned my Non-Provisional Patent Application - What Now?

Tags: patent-applications, non-provisional, revive

I unintentionally abandoned my non-provisional patent application because I ended up in a still-pending legal dispute with the attorney who filed that application on my behalf (I since have filed a Revocation of Power of Attorney form). By the time I understood what was going on with the application, it was given an "abandoned" status by the USPTO. Unfortunately, that was more than five years ago...

1) Given that the dispute with my attorney is well-documented and in current legal proceedings, is there any recommended way to revive the abandoned application with the USPTO?

2) If not, is it possible for me to simply re-file it as a new non-provisional patent application with the same title and modified/improved claims? (I do not believe any similar applications have been filed but I would do a prior-art search before refiling.)

Thank you.

Comment: It wasn't published, was it? Interesting question. Unintentional delay can revive normal patents, but provisionals and after five years ... I wouldn't bet on it. I don't think you'll get a definite answer to that as it's a very rare case. Maybe try calling the uspto.

Comment: It was in fact published by the USPTO site as publication type "application".

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't see the “non“ and thought it was a provisional. That changes everything.

Comment: "Changes everything"--how? Does that mean I have no options or that I do have options?

Comment: it makes your application prior art against your future applications, which is basically pretty bad. I don't know if reviving if possible, but I guess rather not anymore. Let me see if I can compile you an answer later.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if re-applying as the original inventor who submitted the published prior art might get me around the revival issue... Prior art against myself is an admittedly unusual situation... I wonder if my published application could be considered as a first-to-file privilege instead of a document that bars me from any further action, especially since no intervening applications for the same inventions have been published? I also wonder if I might get special consideration because my patent attorney bailed on a prepaid job, leaving me without legal counsel...?

Comment: the grace period for publications by the inventor is one year in the US, after that your own publication is prior art even for your applications. It's anything but unusual to have your own publications cited against you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

US patents and applications can be revived if the relevant fees are paid and a statement is made that the delay was unintentional. In theory, there is no time limit on this. See https://www.uspto.gov/patents-application-process/petitions/09-revival-based-unintentional-delay

You could state your case in the petition trying to show that the entire delay was unintentional.

I have no practical experience with this but strongly suspect that five years are to long. However, if you do try, please add an answer here afterwards to tell us how it went.

It does seem to be your best bet as any published application becomes prior art for new applications and the us grace period for your own publications is one year. Therefore your old application will be prior art for a new filing, no exemptions.

Comment: I will post back here if I have success reviving. I may even try to make an appointment and fly to DC/VA if necessary to explain the detail behind this unusual case. Thanks.

Comment: @Jazimov try calling first ;) oh and in case that's important, you won't be able to get a PCT application or any patent outside the us anymore, even if the us one is revived